# Sword in the Stone story where the sword was held in place by electromagnets

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, arthurian

So some years ago I read a story that included a "sword in the stone" bit and it was explained that the sword was held in place by electromagnets that could be released when "the one" tried to pull the sword out.

I don't remember how integral to the story this bit was (it might have been just an aside about how the current king had been picked). I also don't remember if this was part of a full novel or just a short story. I *think* time travel was involved as the setting was "fantasy-esque" and the whole electricity/magnet connection was obviously an anachronism.

Comment: As a side note: This sword scheme was once used as a key plot point in an episode of the now-cancelled TV program 'Banacek'.

Comment: Oddly related recent WorldBuilding question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/141322/702

Comment: It also appears in the Scorpion series (one episode occurs in a medieval festival and someone acts as Arthur releasing the sword but a genius notices and reveals that there's an electromagnet maintaining it)

Comment: Another side note: the trick (or one very much like it) works well.  I was the adult from the audience of a magic show who couldn't lift a box a child could. It was held down with a large electromagnet in a stand that was weighted down with my own weight, and had a steel plate in the bottom.  I'm a scientist/engineer so I spotted it despite the well-disguised switch - but of course I didn't let on.

Comment: @jpmc26 I posted an answer there, but wanted to track down the source of my inspiration in order to improve my answer. Hence this question.

Comment: @ChrisH: That's downright dangerous! Anyone with metal implants could suffer internal injuries. Worse still, anyone with pacemakers could die.

Comment: @user21820 it doesn't have to be that strong a magnet with a large contact area, and I think it was DC anyway so induction wan't a worry (nowhere to run a cable but somewhere that would hide a car battery)

Comment: @user21820 Actually, Inverse Square law says it's not particularly. Also since the setting was medieval anyone with heart problems probably already died instead of getting pacemakers.

Comment: @aslum: Don't be so careless with lives that are not your own. In the first place, magnetic field strength does not follow an inverse square law but roughly an inverse cube law. This means that while it's less dangerous far away, the magnet can become rapidly more dangerous as you get closer.

Comment: @ChrisH: I said nothing about induction. How dangerous of course depends on the setup, but you said "large electromagnet" and so I won't be surprised if the participants could get close enough to the magnet itself. In any case, there is ample moral reason to be careful with unnecessary strong magnetic fields in public. I don't think there's anything more for me to say.

Comment: @user21820 Pointing out that there was no such thing as pacemakers in the middle ages isn't exactly being careless w/ lives. Also cube vs square would become weaker faster.

Comment: @user21820 well any AC component is the bigger risk hence induction.  Anyway it's not my setup, not even in my country, so not my problem - or yours.

Comment: @ChrisH: I was talking about the magic show that you attended. I hope you reconsider your apparently cavalier attitude to the possibility that negligence with strong magnets hurts someone.

Comment: @user so was I.  goodbye

Comment: @aslum: As I said, I was not talking about your fictional story but about the real life magic show where strong magnetic fields can be dangerous. And do think properly through the implications rather than just making random assumptions about inverse cubic versus square.

Answer (score 36):

This may be "Once and Future" by the late Terry Pratchett, first published in *Camelot* in 1995.  A time-travelling historian named "Mervin" gets stranded in an anachronism stew that mostly matches Arthurian legend, and he reproduces the sword-in-a-stone bit in order to get a king who will follow his advice for advancing technology.

> All the mechanical ways of doing it I had to rule out.  That left electricity.  Strange thing is, it's a lot easier to make a crude electrical generator than a crude steam engine.  The only really critical things are the bearings.
>
> And the copper wire.

And then, when the sword is pulled, Mervin finds out how this Albion is different from ours:

> Uther had a *daughter* in this world.

Comment: I think this is it... I'll double check and then mark correct if so!

Answer (score 10):

It's been a long time since I read them, but I believe Merlin used a lodestone (magnet, but not electromagnet) in this way in A. A. Attanasio's *The Dragon and the Unicorn* series.  Sadly I can't find a ready summary now.

Comment: Can confirm.  That series consistently treats electromagnetic phenomena as a type of magic, starting with the identification of the "Storm Tree" (Yggdrasil) with the earth's magnetic field.

Answer (score 6):

It also showed up in *Interstellar Patrol II the Federation of Humanity*, by Christopher Anvil.  It wasn't a time-travel story, but there was absolutely a sword in a stone that was being used to determine a ruler, and people mucking about with magnets to mess with the situation.

([excerpt link](https://books.google.com/books?id=dQFUjlLoCpUC&pg=PT203&lpg=PT203&dq=interstellar%20patrol%20sword%20in%20stone&source=bl&ots=S8mWH9JpDA&sig=ACfU3U14_gZ6jadjDOlDEM4gxdEMKrN6ZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA5Mbr8P_gAhXPqlkKHUF8BDoQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=interstellar%20patrol%20sword%20in%20stone&f=false))

Comment: I thought of this one, too, it does seem to fit